# plot how many times each list entry is repeated using pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have `list` containing votes (smth like this `votes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4]`). How to use `pyplot` to plot a graph showing the count of each vote (i.e. 1 -> 3 votes, 2 -> 1 vote, 3 -> 2 votes, 4 -> 4 votes)

Here is how I am doing it:

```
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

votes = [1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4]
tmp_votes_count = Counter (votes)
votes_count = []

for i in tmp_votes_count:
    votes_count.append ([i, tmp_votes_count[i]])

plt.plot([row[0] for row in votes_count], [row[1] for row in votes_count])
plt.axis([0,4,0,20])
plt.show()
```

Is there a more optimized way to do it?
Also how to style the graph as bar chart instead of the continuous line? 
I mean smth similar to this:

[image]

instead of what I am getting right now:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
plt.bar([row[0] for row in votes_count], [row[1] for row in votes_count])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know `pandas` , it will be very easy.

```
votes=pd.DataFrame(data=votes,columns=['List'])
votes.List.hist()
```

Comment: Could I bother you to vote your conscience on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46165056/2336654

Comment: @piRSquared sure thing ~ :)

Comment: @piRSquared I appreciate you bring me to your answer, I am learning it ...a lot of new things...:)